# DAO, Spring, Hibernate, Jboss

Tags: hibernate, spring, jboss, dao

How exactly are these 4 components related, any good explanations someone can offer or links or whatever useful.

Answer (score 3):

[JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/) is an application server that can run applications built with

[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about) which is a framework that provides many niceties for Java EE, including integration with ORM layers such as

[Hibernate](https://www.hibernate.org) which lets you map your objects into a RDBMS and store / retrieve those objects using

[DAO pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object)

... [in the house that Jack built](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_the_House_That_Jack_Built).

Answer (score 2):

Briefly, they are different animals :

- JBoss is an application server
- Spring is a J2EE framework that can do lots and lots of things for you
- DAO is mainly a design pattern. But it can be viewed as the data access layer or implementation of that, it depends a bit of the context where you're using the term
- Hibernate is a persistence framework ( so is iBatis for instance )

Maybe you could refine a bit your question, as it is it's a bit vague and it involves some guesswork in regard to what you're exactly interested in finding out.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss is a server that runs it all.
Spring is a set of Java and XML technologies that tie together web applications.
Hibernate is a object relational mapping tool; it lets you talk to your database in a consistent way.
DAO is a data access object, which would be how Spring talks to Hibernate.  (Spring can also talk to iBATIS, or several other technologies to accomplish this.)

Answer (score 1):

JBoss is a server. You can use this to run, for example, a web application that uses Spring as its framework.

If you have a database in your application you have to access it. Hibernate is a framework that helps you with that.

The DAO is a pattern to access the database and you can use here tools that Hibernate provides.